# How do you eliminate this constant from this summation?

Tags: summation

I was trying to help some friends with their math homework, and I am completely stumped. Now I am curious myself on how to solve it:

**Determine the following sum, in terms of n: Summation from i = 0 to n, of (-1)^k * (n choose k) * 10^k**

These are all of the details given for the problem. I have to assume that k is just some arbitrary constant, but even that is not given. Is it possible to eliminate k entirely from the result? Or did the teacher just make a mistake, where they should have said "Determine the following sum, in terms of n *and k*"?

Comment: Well, note that $i$ does not appear in your sum.  I expect that $i=k$.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the teacher intended $k$ to be the summation index.

Note that (assuming $i$ and $k$ are different) there is no $i$ in your sum, so as it stands the sum is just $(n+1)\times (-1)^k\times \binom nk\times 10^k$.

Of course, if $k=i$, the summation index, then this sum becomes a simple case of the binomial theorem.

Comment: If that is the case (i and k are different), then shouldn't it be (n + 1) multiplied by everything, not just n multiplied?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I will edit accordingly.  But, really, they just meant $i=k$.